# precacheImage with SvgPicture in Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, svg, dart

How to use `precacheImage()` with `SvgPicture` from `flutter_svg: 0.17.4` package?

I would like to load the svg picture in the background

```
  Container _graphicSection() {
    final String graphic = 'assets/graphic/two_people.svg';
    return Container(
        child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        SvgPicture.asset(
          graphic,
          height: 150,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
        )
      ],
    ));
  }
```

have anybody any idea how to load svg picture with `precachImage()` function?

Comment: it returns a `Future` so as always in such cases use `FutureBuilder`

Comment: can you show me an example?

Comment: there are tons of examples on how to use `FutureBuilder`, just google for `flutter FutureBuilder`

Comment: no, you're wrong, problem is with ```precachePicture``` function which don't support my SvgPicture

Comment: and normal `SvgPicture.asset` works just fine?

Comment: yes, my example is above

Answer (score 2):

> `flutter_svg` now has a function called `precachePicture()` and you can use it like this:

```dart
Future<void> loadPictures() async {
  await precachePicture(
    ExactAssetPicture(SvgPicture.svgStringDecoder, 'assets/graphic/two_people.svg'),
    context,
  ); //here context can also be null    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`precachePicture` has been deprecated, we can you `SvgAssetLoader` as alternative.

```
void main() async {
  ImageUtils.svgPrecacheImage();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Specify all assets images in utils class.

```
 class ImageUtils {
    
      static const String imageHistory = 'assets/images/ic_history.svg';
      static const String imageShared = 'assets/images/ic_shared.svg';
      static const String imageMap = 'assets/images/ic_maps.svg';
    
    
     static void svgPrecacheImage() {

        const cacheSvgImages = [  /// Specify the all the svg image to cache 
          ImageUtils.imageHistory,
          ImageUtils.imageShared,
          ImageUtils.imageMap,
        ];
    
        for (String element in cacheSvgImages) {
          var loader = SvgAssetLoader(element);
          svg.cache
              .putIfAbsent(loader.cacheKey(null), () => loader.loadBytes(null));
        }

      }
    
    }
```